# Create new instance of an object from an array of unknown types

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to perform a deep copy on a custom data structure.  My problem is that the array (`object[]`) that holds the data I want to copy is of many different types (`string`, `System.DateTime`, custom structures etc).  Doing the following loop will copy an object's reference, so any changes made in one object will reflect in the other.

```
for (int i = 0; i < oldItems.Length; ++i)
{
  newItems[i] = oldItems[i];
}
```

Is there a generic way to create new instances of these objects, and then copy any of the values into them?

P.s. must avoid 3rd party libraries

Comment: Would serialization suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Automapper is out of the question (as @lazyberezovsky noted in his answer), you can serialize it for the copy:

```
public object[] Copy(object obj) {
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        return (object[])formatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
}

[Serializable]
class testobj {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static object[] list = new object[] { new testobj() { Name = "TEST" } };

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        object[] clonedList = Copy(list);

        (clonedList[0] as testobj).Name = "BLAH";

        Console.WriteLine((list[0] as testobj).Name); // prints "TEST"
        Console.WriteLine((clonedList[0] as testobj).Name); // prints "BLAH"
    }
}
```

Note though: this would all be horribly inefficient.. surely there's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [automapper](http://automapper.org/) (available from Nuget):

```
object oldItem = oldItems[i];
Type type = oldItem.GetType();
Mapper.CreateMap(type, type);
// creates new object of same type and copies all values
newItems[i] = Mapper.Map(oldItem, type, type);
```